# Right margin on html page different than left margin

Tags: html, css

Inside my div 'container' there appears to be a larger margin on the left side (larger indent) then there is on the right side. Anyone know why I'm getting this behavior? I have removed the ordered list items so there isn't excessive code to view. That shouldn't impact the question I have regarding the code documented below.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Fantastic Hardware/Software Computer Package</title>

<style type="text/css">

body {
    text-align:center;
}

ul li{
    list-style:none;
}

#right{
    float:right;
    width: 400px;
}

#left {
    float:left;
    width: 400px;
}

#container {
    align: center;
    width: 1024px;
    border-width:3px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#00;
    padding:50px;
    margin:50px auto;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<h1 align="center">Custom Hardware/Software System</h1>

<div id="container">

<div id="left">

<ul>
    <li></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="right">

<ul>
    <li></li>

</ul>
</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

As you can see in the picture, there is more space on the left than right.

[image]

Comment: I think You problem is not yet rectified...Please Make a JSFiddle with all you code...

Comment: underline style applying on ul or li?

Comment: I think your problem is with ul and li only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Use the below code in your CSS:

```
*
{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Hope this solves the problem..!

Comment: That works, after further testing I realized that my border only covers the contents in IE, but not Firefox and Chrome. Know why this might be?

Comment: @JimRomeFan I just check in different browsers. It is coming fine..I dont know what problem you are facing..I strongly suggest you to MAke a JSFiddle file with your Full Code..Then you can say here is the exact problem....Hope you understand..!

Comment: I just had to do an overflow: hidden property to get it to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I create fiddle for your question please have a look on it.

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/8TS9a/`
```